Android Emulator Process Terminated Unexpectedly: How to Resolve?
This is a part of the logs from Android Studio. Does anyone know what it means?
2024-12-30 08:07:30,850 [2697180]   INFO - #c.i.o.k.i.KeymapImpl - Data Holder is null!!!!
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.KeymapImpl.actionIdToShortcuts$lambda$3(KeymapImpl.kt:98)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.SynchronizedClearableLazy._get_value_$lambda$1$lambda$0(SynchronizedClearableLazy.kt:41)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference.updateAndGet(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.SynchronizedClearableLazy.getValue(SynchronizedClearableLazy.kt:40)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.KeymapImpl.getActionIdList(KeymapImpl.kt:751)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.KeymapImpl.getActionIdList(KeymapImpl.kt:72)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.ui.ActionsTreeUtil.createOtherGroup(ActionsTreeUtil.java:498)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.ui.ActionsTreeUtil.createMainGroup(ActionsTreeUtil.java:643)

2024-12-30 08:09:55,302 [2841632]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel_API_34 - Android emulator version 35.4.4.0 (build_id 12745630) (CL:N/A)
2024-12-30 08:09:55,302 [2841632]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel_API_34 - Graphics backend: gfxstream
2024-12-30 08:09:55,302 [2841632]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel_API_34 - Found systemPath C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34-ext11\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
2024-12-30 08:09:55,305 [2841635]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel_API_34 - Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
2024-12-30 08:09:55,305 [2841635]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel_API_34 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515

I also received this warning message.
INFO | Android emulator version 35.4.4.0 (build_id 12745630) (CL:N/A) INFO | Graphics backend: gfxstream INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-35\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\

There also opened bug on issuetracker.google.com.

How much free disk space is on the C Drive? Have you completed a full disk check (and reviewed disk errors) and rebooted the system? The error 0xC0000135 sometimes means a file or file system problem. Have you tried with other virtual device types? Was this a fresh install or an upgrade to Android Studio Ladybug?

@JohnHanley 1. I have about 200 GB of free disk space. 2. I haven't checked disk errors since I completed the installation of the Windows OS. 3. Other virtual device types, I haven't tried it yet, but it's an interesting direction—I will check it. 4. This was a fresh install after the Windows installation.
